# Facebook SDK - how to add fields in C#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

The facebook SDK gives this example for passing the registration form fields:

```
var fields = new object[]
     {
      new {name = "name"},
      new {name = "email"},
      new {name = "location"},
      new {name = "gender"},
      new {name = "birthday"},
      new {name = "password", view = "not_prefilled"},
      new {name = "like", description = "Do you like this plugin?",
                                         type = "checkbox",
                                         @default = "checked"},
      new {name = "phone", description = "Phone Number", type = "text"},
      new {name = "captcha"}
      };
```

I want to add a custom typeahead field to that.  Like:

```
new {name = "live",       description = "Best Place to Live", type = "typeahead", categories = ("city, country, state_province")}
```

But when I run that I get errors on the *categories=* syntax.  Saying the categories is an invalid array.  I've tried several different syntaxes and none seem to work.  What's the proper syntax to add the categories?

Comment: You need to specify which type of object you're creating. Unless you're using some kinda of ExpandoObject with a syntax I haven't seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for arrays use []

```
categories = new[] { "city", "country", "state_province" }
```